# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Complete Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I've got lost somewhere along the way with this tutorial (the one at ruby.railstutorial.org), and have an error in my code somewhere. Does anyone have the complete files for the completed application so that I can compare a working version to mine? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the files here on [github](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed)